# Losing focus and clicking on a close button of my window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I've a method triggered when a NSTextField looses focus. This method displays a popup sheet over my current window.

Everything works great except when I've typed something in the text field and successively I close the window by clicking on the close button. In this case:

- the text field loses focus and the method is triggered and it shows the popup

but

- the window is dismissed anyway, because I've clicked the Close button, so the popup is visible only for few seconds.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an [`NSWindowDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowShouldClose%3a) and implement `-windowShouldClose:` to return `NO` if the popup is visible or if the text field was the previous first responder (or however else you're determining that the text field lost focus).

Comment: How do I know if a popup a visible in my window ? Should I add the NSAlert to the iVars of my class ?

Comment: How are you determining if the text field lost focus? You should probably have flag set in that method and then un-set it in the NSAlert handler.